# Cwnd returnd Undefined Value

Tags: mfc, dialog, handle

I want to use Setwindowpos() in global function to change the postiion of one dialog.
So i coded like below

```
CWnd *pWnd = (CWnd*)pMain->GetDlgItem(IDD_TOOLBAR_DIALOG);//GetActiveFrame ();
pWnd->SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndBottom,0,80,45,900,SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

pWnd returns as undefined value.
So i follow this method

```
CToolTab * tab;
tab = new CToolTab();
if(tab->GetSafeHwnd() == 0)
{
 tab = new CToolTab();
 if( tab->m_hWnd != NULL )
 {
 tab->SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndBottom,0,80,45,900,SWP_SHOWWINDOW);   }
}
```

But m_hWnd returns 0x0000.So in both cases SetWindowPos shows assertion error.
How can i get the handle of dialog in Global function?

Comment: Is the dialog object already constructed before calling this global function? i.e. are you calling this before OnInitDialog() or after?

Comment: Actually im using WPF controls in that dialog.For one button in that dialog,im reducing the width of this dailog.Actually that button is WPF button. But i checked by placing normal MFC button.But in tht case also it wont works

Comment: you didn't actually answer @naveen's question. is pMain valid or is it null? Perhaps a bit more of the code would help us help you.

Comment: Actually i couldn't understand naveen question.Actually my button is in that dialog only.so definetly OnInitDialog is get called. Then only im using that button fucntion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i was thinking this through - and then it occurred to me that IDD_TOOLBAR_DIALOG is almost certainly the resource id for the dialog itself not a control on the dialog.  You can't call GetDlgItem referencing the Dialog resource ID and expect to find the window that contains it (It simply won't work and you'll get back a null CWnd* pointer).

What is it that pMain points to? The main application window? Is that the parent to the Dialog?

Where in the code do you create the Dialog that want to move? At that point you must have a valid CWnd derived object for it? One solution would be to hold on to that as member variable to allow you call SetWindowPos on it later when necessary.